# Перенос текста в DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

Мне нужно, чтобы высота нижнего textblock завесила от высоты верхнего textblock.
Вот наглядный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это сделал при помощи stackpanel, но вот TextWrapping перестал работать.
Я тогда попробовал сделать в DockPanel, но также ничего не изменилось.

Как сделать это?

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#FF383838">
            <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Source="{Binding Page1ViewModel.avatar, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"/>
            <DockPanel Margin="130,0,0,0" Background="Red" Height="71" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="130">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" d:Text="Имя Фамилия" Text="{Binding Page1ViewModel.full_name, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Height="23" Width="128"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="status" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:Text="Статус" Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Text="{Binding Page1ViewModel.status, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" Width="128" Height="24"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Уберите все размеры, научитесь позиционировать объекты грамотно, а не при помощи Margin и размеров. Дайте им просто свободу. К примеру, в вашем коде, что в вопросе, вы задаете `Height="71"` у `DockPanel` и `Height="23"` для первого `TextBlock`, что загоняет его в жесткие рамки, которые он не может сдвинуть и из-за которых весь текст за границами контролла оказывается (вы не увидите там переноса, но он есть).

Comment: Из других недочетов: 1. Много лишнего делаете, дублируете значения и т.д. 2. `Margin="130` - если значение большое, то это сразу признак того, что вы делаете что-то не то. 3. `x:Name="textBlock"` - забудьте про это в WPF! 4. `Margin="10,10,10,10"` -> `Margin="10"`. 5. `{Binding Page1ViewModel.avatar, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"` - я вам уже говорил. что это костыль, но вы проигнорировали... 6. `Grid.ColumnSpan="7"` - тоже, если сетка состоит из кучи ячеек, то явно делаете что-то не то.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправил все описываемые Вами недочеты, по мимо билдинга (с этим пока не хочу разбираться), но вот проблема с переносом не было решена (

Comment: Плохо значит исправили, раз не решена, ибо я взял ваш код, удалил там все, что описал в первом комментарии и получил [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS9HK.png), как видите, текст без проблем переносится. А если еще убрать и ширину, то и в ширину текст успешно [подстраивается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT5sJ.png) под размеры контейнера. А по поводу привязок - ооооооочень зря. Это очень простая вещь, у которой надо лишь понять принцип. В будущем вы можете очень сильно пожалеть, да даже сейчас вы делаете уйму лишних телодвижений, когда можно просто `{Binding Status}`... Ну, дело ваше.

Comment: `Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}` однажды вы поймете, что все время это писали в каждую привязку зря.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, но всё равно не понимаю, что у меня не так https://pastebin.com/b9BwCBih

Comment: Наверно.... Все?) У вас весь дизайн построен на "статике", вы загнали все в рамки, со строгими значениями, даже не понимая, что за что отвечает. К примеру, что означает `280*`? 280 пикселей? Нет, это соотношение, то есть, допустим у вас сетка размером 300 единиц, в ней 3 столбца, первому вы задаете к примеру `.5*`, это означает "половина", считается так: 300/3 = 100 (ширина 1 столбца) и далее 100*0.5 = 50, ну а теперь считайте что у вас `280*` выдаст).

Comment: Я вам покажу сейчас проблему вашего интерфейса: [вроде ок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euQnC.png), а если [чуть расширим?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7WA6.png), хм, а если наоборот, [уменьшим](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLiRB.png), кхм, а где половина элементов?! Уехали... Вы скажете "Ну у меня ведь статичный размер окна, все ок!", ну, не совсем, ведь у всех людей разные мониторы, разное разрешение, разный DPI и прочее, да даже тема Windows изменит размер окна, а с ним и все ваши контролы. Так что, хватит страдать ерундой, разберитесь с привязками, и поймите как грамотно размещать объекты в XAML.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ заменить * на pt?

Comment: Как вы к этому интересно пришли? Я ведь сказал, что вы должны освободить элементы, от строгой привязки к размерам, то есть их вообще не должно быть. Дайте элементам свободу, а при помощи `Grid`/`StackPanel`/`Border` и др. "панелями" управляйте их размещением, используйте свойства `*Alignment` и др, чтоб объект был не в левом углу, а например в нижнем правом, вот весь этот комплекс мер поможет вам сделать то, что вы хотите. Допустим, вот приблизительно разметил нужный вам вид, получил [это](https://pastebin.com/1kTvKGaw), как видите, код и читается проще, и все там без проблем отображается.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а то, что вы говорили про Grid. Как там без Width? Что бы на разных экранах выглядело одинаково, я думаю надо Width измерять в Star, с MinWidth и MaxWidth

Comment: В WPF размеры, которые вы указываете, они не в пикселях, а в своем определенном формате, который отлично подстраивается под разные мониторы сам. Другими словами, вам достаточно разместить элементы, так, как хотите, и будет все это отображаться везде +- одинаково. Только повторюсь, не делайте позиционирование при помощи `Margin`, не указывайте везде строгие размеры и др. Допустим вон, разметка выше, картинка там занимает всегда определенные размеры, а правая часть с текстом `5*`, то есть размер будет 5 картинок, ну и вот где бы вы это не отобразили, будет везде одинаковый вид.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете скинуть какой ни будь гайд на эту тему? Я хотел бы, чтобы в маленьком окне элементы становились меньше, а в полноэкранном, наоборот, больше. Но ничего подобного я не нашёл

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi А нету гайдов. Это я не знаю, если бы вы спросили "дайте мне гайд, как сделать сад с такими-то цветами, такими-то деревьями". Все индивидуально, есть книги по ухаживанию за цветками, по их выращиванию, удобрению, паразитам и прочему, но нету такого, где распишут по пунктам именно ваш случай. Также и тут, есть контролы, некая база, есть C#, есть привязки, расширения разметки, и куча др. механизмов, из которых вы и составляете свое приложение. Так что, извините, я не знаю, чего вам скинуть. Могу лишь предположить, что стоит смотреть либо в сторону триггеров, либо в сторону `Viewbox`.